# How to install the binarySearch module?

Tags: python

I need a module, do you know how I can get it?

Currently getting this error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\b\OneDrive\Desktop\Analyse\test_binarySearch.py", line 10, in <module>
    import binarySearch as BS

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binarySearch'
```

Comment: `pip install binary-search`

Comment: What is the `binarySearch` module? There is no module with that name in the Python standard library so you must have downloaded from somewhere…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) installed, you can install [binary-search](https://pypi.org/project/binary-search/) by running the following command:

```
pip install binary-search
```

(If you do not have pip installed, refer to [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) for installation instructions.)

Then you can import the library in your code like this:

```py
import binary_search
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up cmd and type :

```py
pip install binary-search
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just installed it in cmd. But I still get the same error message in Python..

Comment: It's `binary-search` not `binarySearch`

Comment: `import binarySearch as BS` -> `import binary-search as BS`

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a syntax error in Python it says that "binary-search" is invalid syntax?

Comment: My bad, it should be `import binary_search as BS`

Comment: @GameDev: Dash characters (`-`) aren't allowed in Python identifiers (nor module names by inference).